How can gcc optimize separate call of sin(x) and cos(x) into single sincos?
This c++ code is
#include<cmath>
double f1(double a){
    return std::cos(a);
}

double f2(double a){
    return std::cos(a) + std::sin(a);
}

is compiled into the following assembly (https://godbolt.org/z/Y578h1TKx)
f1(double):
        jmp     cos
f2(double):
        sub     rsp, 24
        lea     rdi, [rsp+8]
        mov     rsi, rsp
        call    sincos
        movsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp+8]
        addsd   xmm0, QWORD PTR [rsp]
        add     rsp, 24
        ret

Does this mean that gcc knows the glibc's standard functions and have optimization technique for specific cases using them?

Reopened. This question is about how the compiler does it. The (not) duplicate was about how to calculate both values.

@PeteBecker Wouldn't it be strange if the GNU compiler wasn't aware of its GNU C runtime extensions?

@3CxEZiVlQ glibc is not part of GCC and GCC works with other C standard library implementations as well.

If you want sin(a)+cos(a) then it’s just sqrt(2).sin(a+pi/4). If you really do want cos(a) and sin(a) separately, then exp(i.a) must have those real and imaginary parts.

When compiling GCC itself, you specify a target triple that includes information about the platform and (maybe indirectly) the C standard library implementation used on the target that the compiled GCC will compile for.
For example x86_64-linux-gnu or x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu is a typical target triple for a target that runs Linux on a x86-64 processor with glibc as C standard library implementation.
Similarly x86_64-linux-musl or x86_64-unknown-linux-musl would be a similar target that uses the musl C standard library implementation instead.
Additionally there are -m compiler switches (e.g. -mglibc, -mmusl, ...) to change the assumed target C standard library implementation.
In this way, GCC knows whether or not the target supports the non-standard sincos function and if it does, then it can rewrite calls to std::cos and std::sin, which have semantics that are always known because they are specified by the C++ and C standards, to a call to sincos in the way that you are seeing.
For example if you compile with -muclibc for a Linux target using the uclibc C standard library implementation, then GCC assumes that sincos is not present and won't rewrite to sincos. (Although I think uclibc does actually support sincos.)
With the default configuration (i.e. without any -std=c* or -ansi flag) it is ok for the compiler to rewrite to the non-standard sincos function, even though sincos is not a name reserved by any standard and could therefore be used for a different purpose by the user, because the default options of GCC assume GNU extensions (i.e. -std=gnu++XX instead of -std=c++XX), not strict conformance to the standards.
Unfortunately GCC still performs this transformation even in strict standard conformance mode, where it shouldn't happen. See bug report here.

I think most of the compilers today will optimise separate calls to sin(x) and cos(x) made with the same argument x to a single sincos(x) if the maths library provides it. Beware that not all compilers compute sincos as accurately as they ought to. I think gcc is OK but MS certainly isn't (at least in some of its recent versions). Hardware x87 sincos is fine.

@MartinBrown Clang does it only if -fapprox-func and -fno-math-errno is given (or -ffast-math which includes both). Clang seems to require the first because replacing the calls with sincos can affect the exact result, although the standards do not require any guaranteed accuracy or determinism of the result as far as I can tell. I am not sure why -fno-math-errno is required, maybe because of the glibc bug mentioned in man sincos where sincos didn't set errno properly?
